# Excel VBA Unable to get PivotFields property of the PivotTable class

Tags: excel, vba

The propose of this code is to use filter different drop downs within a pivot table.

The issue came after a MS update and I recreated a power pivot to use the existing vba. However, I got error code Unable to get PivotFields property of the PivotTable class and seems all pivot table method or applications are no longer workable. I tried CurrentPageName as well, but had no luck.

I have seen other similar error code, but seems due to the different way of recreating pivot table, the existing method is not working for my case.

[image]

[image]

I have label pivot table and field name correctly.

```
Dim Pvt As PivotTable

Set Pvt = Triangle.Sheets("TRIANGLE_DATA").PivotTables("TRIANGLE_PIVOT")

Pvt.PivotFields("CAT_IND").CurrentPage = "NonCat"

Pvt.AddDataField Pvt.PivotFields(IncField), "Sum of INC_LOSS", xlSum
```

both PivotFields and AddDataField got the same error mentioned above.

The same code works for other pivot table. I also tried record macro, and it uses format "PivotFields("[Query].[CAT_IND].[CAT_IND]").VisibleItemsList", which works in my case above. However, it equals to an array. Is there any way to equal to a value, where I commented our the line above? as I need to automate a state selection in stead of input all states names manually.

Any help are much appreciated!

automate switching pivot drop down via VBA copying reference value from another workbook.